# How to manually instantiate ActiveRecord truncated objects?

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Working with ActiveRecord and JRuby, I try to invoke a stored procedure on a Database. Using the underlying Java Library I reached a point where I have a hash with the columns specified in the select.

Now I'd like to use this hash to have ActiveRecord models, but I'd like them to look like if I did a classic Model.select(columns).all (with only the columns values, errors when trying to reach the other ones and readonly).

There must be something inside of AR to do this but I can't find anything and all my search leads to all the basic "fetch" tutorials ...

Comment: Post a gist with your tries!

Comment: @NicolasBlanco
Well for now I haven't tried a lot. I have a hash like {'id' => 4, 'name' => 'Foo', 'some_column' => 'Bar'} so all I do is MyModel.new(hash).readonly!.

It's not an ideal solution because I have all the others columns defined with their default value and if my stored procedure return a computed value it won't match.

I have the feeling that my answer is around the #instantiate method of ActiveRecord but I can't find any documentation of what it does...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I kept digging in Rails code and figured out my answer was the instantiate method.

The idea is if you are inside a model called *MyModel* and do this

```
object = instantiate(value1: 1, value2: 'ok')
```

you will have an instance of the MyModel class with theses attributes defined. If the model is supposed to have more columns, they are not defined. The object is readonly.